# R - Create a network from a matrix

Tags: r, igraph

I have a dataset similar to this:

```
Abruzzo<- c(1,0.76,0.8,0.90)
Campania<- c(0.76,1,0.62,0.69)
Calabria <- c(0.80,0.62,1,0.85)
Puglia <- c(0.90,0.69,0.85,1)
X <-data.frame(Abruzzo,Campania,Calabria,Puglia)
row.names(X)<- c ('Abruzzo','Campania', 'Calabria', 'Puglia')
```

This matrix contains cosine similarity values.
I would like to create a network (with igraph) where the 4 nodes (Abruzzo, Campania, Calabria, Puglia) are all interconnected, and the size of the link depends on the corresponding value of the matrix.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have a weighted adjacency matrix. Use `igraph::graph_from_adjacency_matrix`:

```
library(igraph)
X <- as.matrix(X)
diag(X) <- 0
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(X, mode = "lower", weighted = "weight")
plot(g, edge.width = E(g)$weight, edge.label = E(g)$weight)
```

[image]

If you want a directed graph, change mode to `"directed"`.

Comment: Maybe a shorter version `g <- simplify(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(as.matrix(X), mode = "undirected", weighted = "weight")); plot(g, edge.label = E(g)$weight)`

Comment: I've never used `simplify` thanks for the introduction.